# Zsh `which rvm` or `which gem` returns the function contents instead of the path

Tags: rvm, zsh

I've never had this problem before with my other machines but for some reason in ZSH whenever I type

```
which gem
```

or

```
which rvm
```

I get the function contents:

```
gem () {
local result
command gem "$@"
result="$?" 
hash -r
return $result
}
```

instead of it's path. For the life of me I can not figure out why this is happening.

If I switch over to bash I do not have these problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is normal behavior for zsh. The `which` built-in is equivalent to `whence -c`, which shows the definitions of functions. Use `whence`, possibly with a combination of options that does not include `-f` or `-c`, if you don't want this. For example `whence -w gem` will display `gem: function`. If you only want to search for external executables (and not aliases, built-ins, reserved words or functions), use `whence -v`.

Comment: Thanks. That definitely cleared things up for me. I found using the `-p` option with `which` gave me the result I was expecting. The same appears to be true for using `-p` with `whence`.