# My "python" command and "which python" point to different python versions

Tags: python, environment-variables, conda

I am using Anaconda and found the "python" command of all different environments point to one python `/home/ya/anaconda3/bin/python` which is python 3.8. My base environment uses python 3.8 and I installed an environment `myenv` with python 3.7. However, I found when I type `python` within myenv, it always use 3.8 instead of 3.7.

[image]

Comment: If your shell is bash, use `type python`, not `which python`.

Comment: zsh is the only major shell I know of where `which` is a builtin that actually can see into the shell's inner workings; everywhere else it's an external command that can only see the PATH, but doesn't know about functions, aliases, precached PATH lookups, etc -- so it's very often wrong.

Comment: Also, please include shell transcripts in your question as _text_, not screenshots. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122). As an example of screenshots not being very useful -- if you'd posted text we'd be able to know exactly what changed between the two screenshots by looking at your question's edit history; but when the edit history just shows the screenshot URL changing, we don't have any of those details.

Comment: (but srsly, to answer this, I need to see the output of `type python`; or if your shell isn't bash, show us which specific shell it _actually is_).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you so much, I got the reason.  type python returns python alias /home/ya/anaconda3/bin/python.

Comment: That's your problem, then. If you run `/home/ya/anaconda3/bin/python` explicitly you'll get the version you see from just running `python`.

Comment: BTW, one might consider this a duplicate of [different behavior of `which` command in zsh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196061/different-behavior-of-which-command-in-zsh-and-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using zsh (where it's a builtin), `which` can only check the PATH. It doesn't know anything about functions or aliases.

Use `type python` as a more accurate way to see what `python` will run when your shell is bash.