# 'which gem' and 'which rvm' print bash scripts instead of location

Tags: path, rubygems, rvm

I feel that this is a symptom of a nonfunctioning rvm install but I don't know what's going wrong; I used the command on https://rvm.io/m (\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby)

Note: I can install gems successfully

```
myprompt: which gem
gem () {
    typeset result
    (
        typeset rvmrc
        rvm_rvmrc_files=("/etc/rvmrc" "$HOME/.rvmrc") 
        if [[ -n "${rvm_prefix:-}" ]] && ! [[ "$HOME/.rvmrc" -ef "${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc" ]]
        then
            rvm_rvmrc_files+=("${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc") 
        fi
        for rvmrc in "${rvm_rvmrc_files[@]}"
        do
            [[ -s "${rvmrc}" ]] && source "${rvmrc}" || true
        done
        unset rvm_rvmrc_files
        command gem "$@"
    ) || result=$? 
    hash -r
    return ${result:-0}
}
myprompt:
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same "problem", using zsh on Mac OS X. After a bit of searching I found it's actually the standard behaviour. For a more thorough answer check out this SO question [Zsh `which rvm` or `which gem` returns the function contents instead of the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719757/zsh-which-rvm-or-which-gem-returns-the-function-contents-instead-of-the-path)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about that output; `gem` and `rvm` are supposed to be functions.

But I'm a little puzzled as to why `which` shows the functions. What OS/distro are you running? And what shell? It looks like your `which` is a shell built-in command; in bash it isn't, so perhaps you're using csh or zsh.

Comment: tsh on osx. default shell on osx has which.